# Android dynamic form in dialog

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a little form inside a dialog window in my android app but the below code won't work. How do I make it show. It needs to be dynamically built.

Thanks

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView myTV1=new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView myTV2=new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView myTV3=new TextView(getBaseContext());
    EditText myET1=new EditText(getBaseContext());

    myTV1.setText("hello");
    myTV2.setText("world");
    myTV3.setText("now");
    myET1.setText("Enter your name please");

    TableLayout t = new TableLayout(getBaseContext());
    t.addView(myTV1);
    t.addView(myTV2);
    t.addView(myTV3);
    t.addView(myET1);


    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getBaseContext());
    dialog.setContentView(t);

    dialog.show();


   }
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: it wont show........................

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this.
I build a dialog with a custom layout.

```
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LugarActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_valoracion);
            dialog.setTitle("Valorar Lugar");


            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            final RatingBar ratingBarLugar = (RatingBar)            dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarLugar);
            Button btnValorar = (Button)   dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_enviar_valoracion);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            btnValorar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    //code here
                }
            });

            Button btnCancelar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancelar_valoracion);
            btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
```

and in a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarLugar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_enviar_valoracion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_enviar_valoracion"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancelar_valoracion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_enviar_valoracion"
        android:text="@string/btn_cancelar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I hope I've helped :)